# Dynamic PHP Code creation based on MySQL Column Data Types

Tags: php, mysql, code-generation

I am developing a tool that creates PHP classes based on tables in my database.  Most of the functionality is based on data from `SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table`. Each column typically relates to an instance variable in the new class being created.

What I have now is a situation where if a user passes in "twelve" for a variable related to a column of type INT, it doesn't fail, but the value in the database becomes 0.

What I would like is for the class to return false, identifying that the `UPDATE` or `INSERT` could not be completed.

**What approach would you recommend for this?**

What I'm trying now, is to construct an array of column names that contains each column that has a numeric data type (INT, FLOAT etc.). And when the user tries to set a variable, it checks to see if the variable is in this list and then checks the value being set to determine if it is a number.

PHP 5.3.3 using MySQLi

I'm assuming any column that isn't numeric will accept text data.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "What I would like is for the class to return false" - if you mean on "new", that's not the way classes work.

Comment: Advice: STOP now, and check out ORMs out there; e.g: doctirne (http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

Comment: @erenon Thanks for the link, I'm not able/allowed to make that drastic of a change to our current system, but I'll definitely bring it up for future work.

Comment: @EugenRieck Our system currently works on the principle of "return false if the database query fails". So in most cases we can simply poll the database for an error after a query and we know that we need to return false. In this scenario, there is no database level error, so I need to check for the error condition (text passed instead of a purely numeric value) and return false without ever querying the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you are asking is called ORM. There are some good ORM libraries in PHP.

1. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)
2. [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/)
3. [Outlet ORM](http://www.outlet-orm.org/)
4. [Leap ORM for Kohana](http://orm.spadefootcode.com/) ( I use it )
5. [PHP Data Mapper](http://phpdatamapper.com/)

BTW, I answer your question.

If any invalid data is set you can throw an Exception.

See a sample.

```
class MyTable extends DbTable{
    function __set($var, $val){
        switch($var){
            case 'age': // age should be numeric type
                if(!is_numeric($val)){
                    throw new InvalidDataTypeException("$val of $var is not numeric");
                }
             /// do other operation here

             ... 
             ... // more cases
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I'm working towards now. Except instead of the switch($var) I'm doing if(in_array($var, $numericVars)){//check if numeric} and building an array of the variables that should be numeric. SWITCH is probably more efficient, but I feel the array is easier to read and maintain. With my largest table being around 30 columns, the performance difference is not noticeable.

Comment: Also, thanks for the list of ORM though I'm not able to implement them currently.

Comment: Before using any PHP framework, I also built my own Data mapper library.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be for each field to create not only a variable for the value, but also one for the validation function.

Now have some static validation functions such as `MyClass::ValidateInt()`, `MyClass::ValidateFloat()` and friends, the validation function variable for an `INT` field would have `MyClass::ValidateInt`, call this while generating SQL for updating or inserting

Comment: So something like creating "public function validate$varName (){return self::ValidateInt();}"

Comment: Yep. By calling these on SQL creation you can validate the values before hitting the DB, additionally by making them public you give your API consumers more freedom (and less code duplication)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the input, maybe you can integrate jQuery Validate plugin into your kernel class that creates the instance of the database.

For example, you have a column that is INT, with SHOW COLUMNS you can to stablish that this column must have a required decimal number so no one can to submit the form and then insert it to the database if is not correctly validate.

- info:
  http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Client side validation isn't a guaranteed way to say that all data being sent to the server is safe and valid. Need to have server side options.

Answer (score 0):

UI advocates might say accept "twelve", and convert it to "12".

From a programming standpoint, if you must indicate failure outside of the current scope of the function, the typical way to handle this is to raise an exception and let the caller handle the situation.

Comment: The "twelve" to 12 conversion could be handled client side or in code before the database abstraction layer. We don't view it as the DAL's responsibility to consider the context of the data being passed, just the validity.  As for the exceptions, I agree with you but as I'm developing this, others on the team are learning to use it. Nothing else uses exceptions yet, so I'm trying to keep it in their comfort zone to increase adoption.